# What ARIMA model best fits these graphs?

Tags: arima

I have so far concluded that the ACF and PACF show a potential ARIMA (1, 2, 1). Are there any other possibilities of ARIMA models that could also fit this data?

[image]

Comment: Why would you need both "1" terms there?

Comment: Second-order differencing is not common in economics (or perhaps in general). What kind of process do you have? Perhaps second-order differencing does not make sense when viewed from the subject-matter perspective.

Comment: Why can you not have both terms equal to 1, if both show significance at lag 1?

Comment: If you answer a comment by some user, use @username (e.g. @RichardHardy) to make sure the addressee is notified about your message.

Answer (score 1):

When deciding between an AR model and an MA model one looks for dominance between the ACF and the PACF:

- If the ACF dominates then choose an AR model with the order dictated by the PACF.
- If the PACF dominates then choose an MA model with the order dictated by the ACF.
- If there is ambiguity then there might be a combined model BUT I would proceed slowly by selecting one and then reviewing the model residuals to suggest further augmentation.

Recall that the above advice is a rule of thumb and is probably worthless when you have any of the following:

- outliers/pulses/step shifts/local time trends
- parameters that are changing over time
- a model error variance that is non-constant.